# vi visual mode doesn't work

Tags: vim, vi

I'm running vim (7.0.237) after sshing to a remote CentOS box, and it just won't enter visual mode.

When I press 'v', it just beeps and does nothing.

I'm running Ubuntu with GNOME Terminal, and the local copy of vi works fine, so I don't see how this could be a problem with the terminal.  I have the same .vimrc file on the local and remote machines, and the only settings are: set nocompatible; set tabstop=4.

I'm at a total loss here, any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RedHat based systems have a package called `vim-minimal` installed by default, which has a limited set of features enabled.  You want to install the `vim-enhanced` package.

Debian based systems do something similar, where `vim-tiny` is the default install and has a minimal feature set.  Your Ubuntu system must have one of the other Vim packages installed (likely `vim` or `vim-gtk`) which is why it works fine there.

Answer (score 10):

Well it actually seems like you can build vim without support for visual mode. Check the output of `:ver` and see whether it says `+visual` or `-visual`. Bad luck if it's the latter.

Comment: That's correct, thank you.  I awarded the checkmark to the other answer, since he gave a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed vi as `vim-enhanced`, but if I run it as `vi`, `:ver` shows `Tiny version without GUI` and lists `-visual`. When launched as `vim`, it says `Huge version without GUI` (and `+visual`).

Check your `.bashrc` for `alias vi='vim'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your local terminal settings are not necessarily transferred correctly via SSH; do other programs that use termcap/terminfo (e.g. top, less) work through the SSH link?

Another thing to try: manually setting the TERM environment variable to "vt100" and see whether that has any effect.

Comment: Yup, the 'v' key works fine in less.  I don't see how this could be a terminal issue at all, in that case.  Must be something weird with that particular version or configuration of vi.